# Bean property 'bagBisDomainService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring

I have a "Bean property 'bagBisDomainService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method" error when I execute my spring web application. Below is my code :

```
public class StatusSynthesisFlightsAction extends WDispatchAction {

protected FlightListeCritereForm criteriaForm = null;

/**
 * Reference sur le domain service
 */
private BagDS bagBisDomainService;

/**
 * Reference sur le domain service
 */
 private FlightDS flightBisDomainService;

 /**
  * @return the bagBisDomainService
  */
 public BagDS getBagBisDomainService() {
     return bagBisDomainService;
 }


 /**
  * @param bagBisDomainService the bagBisDomainService to set
  */
 public void setBagBisDomainService(BagDS bagBisDomainService) {
     this.bagBisDomainService = bagBisDomainService;
 }


 /**
  * @return the flightDomainService
  */
 public FlightDS getFlightBisDomainService() {
     return flightBisDomainService;
 }
```

}

```
<bean name="/statusSynthesisFlights" class="com.afklm.srbview.applicationlayer.action.flight.StatusSynthesisFlightsAction" scope="singleton">
    <property name="bagBisDomainService" ref="bagDSImpl"/>
    <property name="flightBisDomainService" ref="flightDSImpl"/>
</bean>
```

Any Idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a setFlightBisDomainService() method?

Comment: @indybee Yes, there is a setFlightBisDomainService() method. But I get it, the problem comes from my struts-config.xml. Below explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1) Re build after clean and try. 
2) public class StatusSynthesisFlightsAction extends WDispatchAction implements serializable if 1) fails.